# Separate React build with fonts included

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, fonts

I have a **React JS** project that uses Google Fonts via URL import in SASS files.

Now I need to have the same exact version, but for standalone local network, **without Internet** available - meaning **the fonts should be included**.

I'd like to have an option to create separate builds for each case, while keeping the project the same, ideally with some **.env** trick, without ejecting React and splitting webpack configs.

One way would be to do it via JS, putting the font file in public folder and adding the links to DOM based on some config setting, but there's probably some way to include them in the bundle based on build configuration - that I'm not aware of. Or maybe use different .html files for each case?

Is there a standard way to do this?
If anyone has done this, please share your experience :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...I ended up with a JS bit in App component that loads the needed CSS based on a value in .env and using separate .envs for each case via `env-cmd`.

Here's the App.js code, maybe it'll help somebody:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.scss";
import Main from "./components/Main";
import Notification from "./components/template/Notification";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";
import theme1 from "./data/theme1";

const { REACT_APP_INCLUDE_FONTS } = process.env;

class App extends React.Component {
  /**
   * Adds a stylesheet to the page DOM.
   * @param {*} href
   * @param {*} rel
   * @param {*} crossorigin
   */
  addStylesheet = (href, rel = "stylesheet", crossorigin = false) => {
    const link = document.createElement("link");
    link.href = href;
    link.rel = rel;
    if (crossorigin) {
      link.crossorigin = crossorigin;
    }
    document.head.appendChild(link);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // FONTS INCLUSION

    // if we are NOT including fonts, use web links
    if (!REACT_APP_INCLUDE_FONTS) {
      // add Noto Sans font from goolge fonts
      this.addStylesheet("https://fonts.googleapis.com", "preconnect");
      this.addStylesheet("https://fonts.gstatic.com", "preconnect", true);
      this.addStylesheet("./fonts/noto-sans/font-web.css");
      return;
    }
    // we ARE including fonts: include Noto Sans font from local file
    this.addStylesheet("./fonts/noto-sans/font-local.css");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme1}>
        <Main />
        <Notification />
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```